# Measurable Function counter example

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $f : R \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ is measurable. Prove or give a counter example.

[a.] if $m(\{ x: f(x) = \infty\}) =0 $ then $f$ is bounded a.e. on $R$

[b.] If $f$ is bounded a.e then $m(\{x : f(x) = \infty\})=0$

I can't find any example any idea, Thanks

Comment: Think about it. $f(x) = x^2$ for example.

Comment: so, for this function $f(x) = x^2$ we have $m(\{x : f(x)=\infty\})=0$ but $f$ is not bounded, am i saying correct?

Comment: "bounded a.e." doesn't really make sense. I think you want to say "finite a.e."

Comment: it said bounded

Comment: @Lucas What is "bounded a.e." supposed to mean?

Comment: @zhw you raise a good question, i can tell you for sure it said bounded here, but you are right

Comment: "bounded a.e." means there is a constant $M\in(0,\infty)$ such that $m(\{x:f(x)>M\})=0$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: any counter example for these problems?

Comment: @Batman gave you a (counter)example for (a), and now that you have a definition of "bounded a.e." in hand, (b) should be clear.

Comment: Counter-example to [a.] As @Batman suggested. The function $f(x)=x^2$ is measurable and $m(\{x\,:\<f(x)=\infty\})=0$  BUT $f$ is not bounded a.e.

Comment: On the other hand, [b.] is true and as @JohnDawkins pointed out you can easily prove it.

Comment: I am clear on [a] but still can't see an counter example for [b] sorry

Comment: There is no counter exemple for [b].  The item [b] is true.  Suppose $f$ is bounded  a.e.. It means  there is a constant $M\in (0,\infty)$ such that $m(\{x\,:\,f(x)>M\})=0$. So we have $m(\{x : f(x) = \infty\})=0$.